# Как установить docker так, чтобы он работал через virtualbox, а не wsl? Hyper-v включен. OS - Windows

Tags: docker, администрирование, virtualbox

Можно ли вообще так на Windows 10 или это просто не возможно? Или все же это возможно но это будет менее производительно чем wsl?

Comment: Ээээ... у тебя не получается поставить докер внутрь ОС, которая крутится в Виртуалбоксе?

Comment: я о том, чтобы докер эмулировался через virtualbox, а не через wsl.

Comment: `докер эмулировался через virtualbox`... эээ... либо я что-то не понимаю. Либо у тебя каша в голове. Докер - это надстройка над ядром линукса, в котором есть кусочки разделения прав для кучи штук. Без ядра линукса докер не пашет. Виртуалбокс - это виртуальная машина, в которую можно поставить любую операционку (и винду и линукс и реактос). Ты либо ставишь внутрь виртуалбокса линукс и внутрь линукса ставишь докер, либо я что-то упустил.